# Jest and enzyme tests snippet

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Am having this file and I want to test it but some of the lines are not covered, how can I test them with Jest and Enzyme in reactjs.

```
const List = props => (
    <div className={styles['comments-list']}>
        <h5 className={styles['comment-header']}>Comments</h5>
        <ul className="collection">
            {props.comments.map(comment =>
                <li className="collection-item avatar" key={comment.id}>
                    <img src={IMG} alt="" className="circle"/>
                    <span className="title"><b>{comment.author}</b></span><br/>
                    <span className={`title ${styles['date-font-size']}`}><i>{formatDate(comment.created_at)}</i></span>
                    <p className={styles['comment-body']}>
                        <br/>
                        {comment.body}
                    </p>
                    <div className="secondary-content">
                        <i className={`material-icons ${styles['icon-red']}`} onClick={event => props.deleteComment(comment.id)}>delete</i>
                        <i className="material-icons" onClick={(e) => {
                            $('#foo').modal('open')
                            props.editComment(comment)
                        }}>edit</i>
                        <i className="material-icons">reply</i>
                    </div>

                </li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

From the snippet above the following lines are not tested, but the rest are :

```
<li className="collection-item avatar" key={comment.id}>

<i className={`material-icons ${styles['icon-red']}`} onClick={event => props.deleteComment(comment.id)}>delete</i>



$('#foo').modal('open')
props.editComment(comment)
```

Now those lines of code above are the lines which are not tested in my project , how can I test them in Jest or Enzyme.

The following is one of the test am having :

```
it('should test List component', () => {

        wrapper = shallow(
            <List deleteComment='Success!'  editComment={jest.fn} comments={[]} handleChange={jest.fn} body={''} />
        );

        const tree = renderer.create(<List comments={[]}  handleChange={jest.fn} body={''} />).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
        expect(wrapper.find('li')).toHaveLength(0)

        expect(wrapper.props().deleteComment).toEqual(undefined)
        expect(wrapper.props().editComment).toEqual(undefined)


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you provide empty comments list `comments={[]}` therefore the code inside `props.comments.map` is never executed. Add one more test that checks whether your component renders comments:

```
it('should test List component with comments', () => {

    const comments = [
        {
            id: 1,
            author: 'John',
            body: 'Hello world'
        }
    ];

    const wrapper = shallow(
        <List deleteComment='Success!'  editComment={jest.fn} comments={comments} handleChange={jest.fn} body={''} />
    );
});
```